# Acessing a JSON object using jQUery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to access a jQuery JSON object, and I can't see anything wrong witj my code, but all I get when I try to access the object is `undefined`, I was thinking that maybe it's because of the way it is nested, but I am unsure, here is my code,

```
 function systems(dom_id, id){
  $.getJSON("get_systems.php", {uid:id}, function(data){
  // here I get the general system info related to the user 
     $.each(data, function(i, json){
    //here I get each systems name, related to each system
    $.getJSON('get_system_name.php', {uid:json.product_id}, function(data){
     console.log(data.products);
     $(dom_id).append('<tr><th>'+data.products+'</th></tr>');
    });

   });

  });
 };
```

The column name with the name of the system in it, is named `products`, hence me trying to get the name using `data.products`, but all I get is `undefined` as I mentioned above.

But when I just log `data` it shows the object, which looks like this, `[Object { products="this is the product name"}]` and this is the PHP that I use to get the system names,

get_system_name.php:

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("the_DB") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT products FROM products WHERE product_id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query, true)) {
 $string[] = $array;
}

$json = json_encode($string);
echo $json;
?>
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object". Either it is a JSON string, or it is a native object.

Comment: Edit the question to add the json output (by going directly to the url in the browser)

Comment: Thanx, still new to all of this, so please excuse my ignorance, but thank you for the correction, might I ask where I can learn more on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of this line:
`[Object { products="this is the product name"}]`

data is actually an array of JSON, not a JSON. So if you did

`data[0].products`

, it should work. You might want to look into why it's coming back as an array though, unless that's your desired behaviour.

Comment: Got it working! It was pushing each JSON string into an array, which was not needed since I was only getting one name each time, so I changed the code to just return a string instead of an array with JSON strings in it, and now it works fine! Thanx alot!

Comment: Well done. I'd of helped further, but I don't know much php, so say anything other than I knew it was being pushed into an array.